# Django - Pivot data

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am preparing a report where the output needed is something like a pivot table. I am able to get the required output numbers but not in desired format.

Below is the query that i have written for getting the data.

```
net2 = AccountNetworkMapping.objects.filter(accountId=24).values_list('accountId__accountName','serviceFunctionName', 'networkCode',
                                                                     'cji3report__period').annotate(Sum('cji3report__valInRepCurrency'))
```

Now i am getting a queryset with something like this

```
('Acc1', '1st Level Ops', 10048666, 1, Decimal('1996'))
('Acc1', '1st Level Ops', 10048666, 2, Decimal('1868'))
('Acc1', '1st Level Ops', 10048666, 3, Decimal('872'))
('Acc1', '2nd Level Ops', 10048667, 4, Decimal('119.4'))
('Acc1', '2nd Level Ops', 10048667, 5, Decimal('128.2'))
('Acc1', '2nd Level Ops', 10048667, 6, Decimal('127'))
('Acc1', '2nd Level Ops', 10048667, 7, Decimal('135'))
('Acc1', 'Dispatch', 10069920, None, None)
('Acc1', 'Incident Mgmt.', 10048674, 1,Decimal('6067.71
('Acc1', 'Incident Mgmt', 10048674, 2, Decimal('5276.65
('Acc1', 'Incident Mgmt', 10048674, 3, Decimal('6077.88
('Acc1', 'Incident Mgmt', 10048674, 4, Decimal('4617.83
('Acc1', 'Incident Mgmt', 10048674, 5, Decimal('5125.52
('Acc1', 'Incident Mgmt', 10048674, 6, Decimal('4630.80
('Acc1', 'Incident Mgmt', 10048674, 7, Decimal('5502.61
('Acc1', 'Operations mgmt', 10048673, 1, Decimal('1914.18'))
('Acc1', 'Operations mgmt', 10048673, 2, Decimal('9371.42'))
('Acc1', 'Operations mgmt', 10048673, 3, Decimal('6550.40'))
('Acc1', 'Operations mgmt', 10048673, 4, Decimal('5687.95'))
('Acc1', 'Operations mgmt', 10048673, 5, Decimal('5885.44'))
('Acc1', 'Operations mgmt', 10048673, 6, Decimal('448.20'))
('Acc1', 'Operations mgmt', 10048673, 7, Decimal('3393.38'))
('Acc1', 'Optimization', 10048671, 1, Decimal('17664.03'))
('Acc1', 'Optimization', 10048671, 2, Decimal('23518.47'))
('Acc1', 'Optimization', 10048671, 3, Decimal('23676.25'))
('Acc1', 'Optimization', 10048671, 4, Decimal('20782.41'))
('Acc1', 'Optimization', 10048671, 5, Decimal('34348.31'))
('Acc1', 'Optimization', 10048671, 6, Decimal('12187.35'))
('Acc1', 'Optimization', 10048671, 7, Decimal('19059.12'))
('Acc1', 'Service', 10048670, 3, Decimal('12.12'))
('Acc1', 'Service ', 10048670, 4, Decimal('12.12'))
```

Now the problem i am facing is that i want to display the above content in below format

```
Service Function   Network  Jan  Feb  March  April  May   June  July  
1st LA Ops        10048666  1996 1868  872   0        0     0     0
2nd LA Ops        10048666    0    0    0   119.4  128.2  127   135
```

Pls guide how can i prepare this table in django

Answer (score 0):

This django library can do what you want: https://github.com/martsberger/django-pivot. After `pip install django-pivot` something like:

```
from django_pivot.pivot import pivot

result_you_want = pivot(AccountNetworkMapping.objects.filter(accountId=24),
                        ['serviceFunctionName', 'networkCode'],
                        'cji3report__period',
                        'cji3report__valInRepCurrency')
```

You can specify that the aggregation you want is `Sum`, but that's the default.